# How to Organize Text Into Rows After Keyword Excel

Tags: excel, format, dataset

I am working on a machine learning project and am using Excel to handle the dataset. I am new to both Excel and ML.

So I am using [this dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/cleveland.data), and I just copy pasted the whole thing into an excel spreadsheet. I did text to columns, and after this is where I am stuck. Here's a snapshot of some of the data:

[Snapshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPhiG.png)

I want to reformat the data in the spreadsheet so that all of the data goes into a single row, then starts a new row after the "name" keyword.

For example, I want this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

19 20 21 22 23 name
```

to become:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 name (all on one line)
```

without having to do it manually line by line (it is almost 3000 lines long).

How would I go about doing this (with VBA if needed)? Thanks!

Comment: This can't be done with excel formulas. Will need `VBA` or other tool

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use VBA. I used the following sample data:

[image]

And got the following output:

[image]

With this macro:

```
Sub separateByName()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lCol2 As Long

k = 1

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lRow
lCol = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For j = 1 To lCol

    lCol2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(k, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(k, lCol2 + 1).Value = Cells(i, j).Value
    If Cells(i, j).Value = "name" Then k = k + 1

Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! I used this code but got a seemingly random result (some rows mixed, skipped, repeated, etc.). Could I maybe get some clarification on how the code works (new to VBA)? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your data and the result?